Powershell interfacing with MobaXTerm get's stuck when SSHing to IP
I have the following PowerShell code below:
# SSH connection parameters
$sshHost = "MyIP"
$sshUsername = "MyUsername"
$sshPassword = "MyPassword"

# Commands to execute within the SSH session
$commands = @"
echo Hello, this is a test
ls -l
"@

# Write commands to a temporary script file
$scriptFile = "C:/temp/commands.sh"  # Use Unix-style path for remote execution
$commands | Out-File -FilePath $scriptFile -Encoding ascii

# Path to MobaXterm executable
$MobaXtermPath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mobatek\MobaXterm\MobaXterm.exe"

# Start MobaXterm SSH session and execute the script file
Start-Process -FilePath $MobaXtermPath -ArgumentList "-newtab", "-ssh", "$sshUsername@$sshHost", "-cmd", "chmod +x $scriptFile && sh $scriptFile"

I get this error when the script runs:
/bin/bash: -c: option requires an argument

This doesn't seem to connect to the IP I have in place. I am not sure where I am going wrong with my arguments and don't see many help topics in this area.

I was able to connect by changing my syntax a bit. However I found out MobaXTerm doesn't allow you to connect and then run a command so I guess this was a dead end. Here below is the syntax used to connect:
# SSH connection parameters
$sshHost = "MyIP"
$sshUsername = "MyUsername"
$sshPassword = "MyPassword"

# Build the SSH command with double quotes
$sshCommand = "ssh $sshUsername@$sshHost"

# Commands to execute within the SSH session
$commands = @"
echo Hello, this is a test
ls -l
"@

# Write commands to a temporary script file
$scriptFile = "C:/temp/commands.sh"  # Use Unix-style path for remote execution
$commands | Out-File -FilePath $scriptFile -Encoding ascii

# Path to MobaXterm executable
$MobaXtermPath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mobatek\MobaXterm\MobaXterm.exe"

# Start MobaXterm SSH session and execute the script file
Start-Process -FilePath $MobaXtermPath -ArgumentList "-newtab", "`"$sshCommand`""

